# How to continuously read a binary file in Crystal and get Bytes out of it?

Tags: binaryfiles, crystal-lang

Reading binary files in Crystal is supposed to be done with `Bytes.new(size)` and `File#read`, but... what if you don't know how many bytes you'll read in advance, and you want to keep reading chunks at a time?

Here's an example, reading 3 chunks from an imaginary file format that specifies the length of data chunks with an initial byte:

```
file = File.open "something.bin", "rb"
```

The following doesn't work, since `Bytes` can't be concatenated (as it's really a `Slice(UInt8)`, and slices can't be concatenated):

```
data = Bytes.new(0)

3.times do
    bytes_to_read = file.read_byte.not_nil!
    chunk = Bytes.new(bytes_to_read)
    file.read(chunk)
    data += chunk
end
```

The best thing I've come up with is to use an `Array(UInt8)` instead of `Bytes`, and call `to_a` on all the bytes read:

```
data = [] of UInt8

3.times do
    bytes_to_read = file.read_byte.not_nil!
    chunk = Bytes.new(bytes_to_read)
    file.read(chunk)
    data += chunk.to_a
end
```

However, there's then seemingly no way to turn that back into `Bytes` (`Array#to_slice` [was removed](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/5173#issuecomment-340286755)), which is needed for many applications and [recommended by the authors to be the type of all binary data](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/1681#issuecomment-222208685).

So... how do I **keep reading from a file**, **concatenating to the end of previous data**, and **get `Bytes` out of it**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution would be to copy the data to a resized Bytes on every iteration. You could also collect the Bytes instances in a container (e.g. Array) and merge them at the end, but that would all mean additional copy operations.

The best solution would probably be to use a buffer that is large enough to fit all data that could possibly be read - or at least be very likely to (resize if necessary).
If the maximum size is just 3 * 255 bytes this is a no-brainer. You can size down at the end if the buffer is too large.

```
data = Bytes.new 3 * UInt8::MAX
bytes_read = 0
3.times do
  bytes_to_read = file.read_byte.not_nil!
  file.read_fully(data + bytes_read)
  bytes_read += bytes_to_read
end
# resize to actual size at the end:
data = data[0, bytes_read]
```

Note: As the data format tells how many bytes to read, you should use `read_fully` instead of `read` which would silently ignore if there are actually less bytes to read.

---

EDIT: Since the number of chunks and thus the maximum size is not known in advance (per comment), you should use a dynamically resizing buffer. This can be easily implemented using `IO::Memory`, which will take care of resizing the buffer accordingly if necessary.

```
io = IO::Memory.new
loop do
  bytes_to_read = file.read_byte
  break if bytes_to_read.nil?
  IO.copy(file, io, bytes_to_read)
end
data = io.to_slice
```

Comment: Sadly, my example was just an example. One of the main reasons I'm using Crystal instead of C is to avoid things like hard-coded limits and allocating a maximum-possible number of entries in advance.

Comment: That was not clearly stated in the question. In this case, you should use an `IO`. I amended an example for that.

Comment: I figured the line "what if you don't know how many bytes you'll read in advance" specified that clearly enough! Thanks a bundle for adding that in - I'll see if I can solve my use case using `IO` and accept this answer if that's the case.

Comment: Yeah, my example didn't quite reflect my use case well enough.